# Refactoring a sequence of methods

Tags: java, java-8, refactoring, option-type

I have a sequence of methods that I need to run sequentially, using the result of each method as a parameter in the next. However, I also check that the result of each method is "good" before calling the next method (if it's "bad" then I exit the method early. The methods return an empty `Optional` if they were not successful.

Is there a refactoring that I can perform to improve the code? *Chain of Responsibility* feels a little overboard.

```
private boolean isSequenceSuccessful() {
  Optional<byte[]> result1 = doSomething();

  if (!result1.isPresent()) {
    return false;
  }

  Optional<byte[]> result2 = doAnotherThing(result1.get());

  if (!result2.isPresent()) {
    return false;
  }

  Optional<byte[]> result3 = doSomethingElse(result2.get());

  if (!result3.isPresent()) {
    return false;
  }

  return doMoreStuff(result3.get());
}
```

I don't want to use Exceptions to control the flow of the method because that's a code smell (I expect to sometimes get "bad" results).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write it shorter using `Optional` and mapping:

```
private boolean isSequenceSuccessful() {
    return Optional.of(doSomething())
            .flatMap(result1 -> doAnotherThing(result1))
            .flatMap(result2 -> doSomethingElse(result2))
            .map(result3 -> doMoreStuff(result3))
            .orElse(false);
}
```

Or using method references even shorter:

```
private boolean isSequenceSuccessful2() {
    return Optional.of(doSomething())
            .flatMap(this::doAnotherThing)
            .flatMap(this::doSomethingElse)
            .map(this::doMoreStuff)
            .orElse(false);
}
```

It depends what you prefer. If you want to keep the intermediate result variables use the lambda version.

Since the methods `doAnotherThing` and `doSomethingElse` do return an `Optional<byte[]>`, `Optional.flatMap` is needed to continue the mapping. Otherwise you could change the return type of these methods to return `byte[]` solely. Then you would use `Optinal.map` only, which would be more consistent.

The mapping will only be performed as long as a value is present in the `Optional`. If all mappings could be applied the value of the last is returned as result. Otherwise the processing will fail fast and bypass all remainig mappings to the last statement `orElse` and return it's value. This is `false` according to your code.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up changing the return types to `byte[]` so I'm using plain `.map()`s instead as per your suggestion.

Comment: It's definitely simpler and since you chain the intermediate results in `isSequenceSuccessful`there is no need for the sub-methods to be aware of how it is done there, namely by means of `Optional`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `map` method:

```
private boolean isSequenceSuccessful() {
  Optional<byte[]> result = doSomething().map(this::doAnotherThing)
                                         .map(this::doSomethingElse);
  if (result.isPresent()) return doMoreStuff(result.get());
  else return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Optional::flatMap`.

```
private boolean isSequenceSuccessful() {
    Optional<Boolean> result = doSomething()
        .flatMap(this::doAnotherThing)
        .flatMap(this::doSomethingElse)
        .map(this::doMoreStuff);
    return result.isPresent() ? result.get() : false;
}
```

Comment: What is the additional value of using `Optional` and then at the end to catch a potential `NullPointerException` instead to use the `Optional` to check if a value is present?

Comment: @LuCio Oh, I thought it will return a null optional. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the template pattern which I sometimes refer to as the pizza pattern because it is analogous to making a pizza. (eg. createDough(), putIngredients(), bake(), package(), deliver()). This might apply to your case. There are several examples and implementations out there but pick and choose which applies best to you. In your example above, I would create an abstract class and create concrete classes/implementations. Example to give you an idea:

```
public abstract class SequenceChecker {

    // ...

    public boolean isSequenceSuccessful() {
        Optional<byte[]> result1 = doSomething();
        Optional<byte[]> result2 = doAnotherThing(result1);
        Optional<byte[]> result3 = doSomethingElse(result2);
        return doMoreStuff(result3);
    }

    protected abstract boolean doMoreStuff(Optional<byte[]> result);

    protected abstract Optional<byte[]> doSomethingElse(Optional<byte[]> result);

    protected abstract Optional<byte[]> doAnotherThing(Optional<byte[]> result);

    protected abstract Optional<byte[]> doSomething();

    // ...
}
```